# How to get exact location coordinates in web browsers (not in mobile) using java script or Vue js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, geolocation

I was building a Vue web application and I need to get exact location coordinates. I tried using a built-in `navigator.geolocation` API as well as `vue-browser-geolocation` plugin . Both are giving inaccurate lat and long. Please suggest a way to get exact user coordinates.

Comment: Define "exact". How much is "inaccurate"?

Comment: @kerbh0lz the result I got now has more than 201744 meters difference is there. By exact, I mean to get my local city coordinates.

Comment: I guess there is no "exact" way of determining the location (unless maybe a user specifically enters his exact location). I think browsers on desktop pcs mostly use IP address to determine the location, which can vary depending on the "dial-in-node" of your hosting provider